# Macbook Pro SD card reader is not listed as USB hardware

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, sd-card

I have 15" early 2011 MacBook Pro with OS X Mavericks installed. Everything works fine, except the SD card reader. Even it's not listed in USB hardware list.

[image]

The SD card slot is dust-free and pins are clean. Resetting the PRAM/SMC has not helped.

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's **not** supposed to be listed under the USB devices at least in Yosemite and El Capitan, not really sure about Mavericks.

[image: As you can see it has it's own tab]

Comment: Ugh. Really? 

Should not it look like this:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/114560

Comment: I found this line : "Parallels Desktop supports USB connected SD card readers. In order to find if you have Card Reader connected via USB, please follow these steps...". It felt as though they were talking about an external reader. Did you check your Card Reader tab? Does it work under OS X?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to answer you. Recently I have updated the OS to El Capitan. And now it looks exactly the same as yours. But problem remains, SD cards are still not recognised.